# Move and scale custom view in android

Tags: android, animation, scale, move, ontouchlistener

I want to create a custom menu for my Android application like iPhone's https://github.com/XavierDK/XDKAirMenu . My application shows menu on left side of the screen and its content on right side of the screen.

This the custom layout for right side of the screen(content view)

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
                gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

                if (isTranformed) {
                    final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
                    final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) this .getLayoutParams();
                        if (layoutParams.leftMargin == 0 && layoutParams.topMargin == 0) {
                            //requestLayout();
                            isTranformed = false;
                            isScrolling = false;
                            break;
                        }
                        isScrolling = true;
                        int xDiff = layoutParams.leftMargin - (X - _xDelta);
                        layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
                        int scaleFactor =  layoutParams.leftMargin > 0 ? layoutParams.leftMargin : 1;
                        layoutParams.topMargin = layoutParams.topMargin - ((layoutParams.topMargin / scaleFactor) * xDiff);

                        if (layoutParams.leftMargin < 0) {
                            layoutParams.leftMargin = 0;
                        }
                        if (layoutParams.topMargin < 0) {
                            layoutParams.topMargin = 0;
                        }
                        layoutParams.width = (displayMetrics.widthPixels - layoutParams.leftMargin);
                        layoutParams.height = (displayMetrics.heightPixels - (layoutParams.topMargin * 2));
                        this.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                        //invalidate();
                        //setLeft(layoutParams.leftMargin);
                        //setTop(layoutParams.topMargin);
        /*              this.setX(layoutParams.leftMargin);
                        this.setY(layoutParams.topMargin);*/
                        this.requestLayout();

                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        if (isScrolling) {
                            FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) CustomSlidingLayout.this
                                    .getLayoutParams();

                            if (params.leftMargin < displayMetrics.widthPixels / 2) {

                                if (!isAnimating) {
                                    isAnimating = true;
                                    ResizeMoveAnimation anim = new ResizeMoveAnimation(
                                            this, 0, 0, displayMetrics.widthPixels,
                                            displayMetrics.heightPixels);
                                    anim.setAnimationListener(animationListener);
                                    startAnimation(anim);
                                }
                            } else {
                                if (!isAnimating) {
                                    isAnimating = true;
                                    Rect rect = new Rect();
                                    getLocalVisibleRect(rect);
                                    ResizeMoveAnimation anim = new ResizeMoveAnimation(
                                            this, (int) (displayMetrics.widthPixels * 0.8),
                                            displayMetrics.heightPixels / 4,
                                            displayMetrics.widthPixels * 2,
                                            (int) (displayMetrics.heightPixels * 0.75));
                                    // anim.setAnimationListener(animationListener);
                                    startAnimation(anim);
                                    isAnimating = false;
                                }
                            }
                            isScrolling = false;
                        }

                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        FrameLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) this
                                .getLayoutParams();
                        _xDelta = X - lParams.leftMargin;
                        break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
```

View on the right side(content view) resize to a small size when click on menu button.and it resize to its original size when touch on the resized view.Also, i want to scale and move the view from right-to left on touch. The above code snippet have  some view position issues. It does not update the view layout/position correctly.How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to achieve the scaling and transition `animation`

```
    float scalefactor = 0.5;
    float translateX = 500; // Translate amount
    view.animate().scaleX(scalefactor).translationXBy(translateX).start();
```

for reverse `animation`

```
    view.animate().scaleX(1).translationXBy(-translateX).start();
```

Comment: I want move and resize(make the scaled(small) view to its original size) while dragging it.Referred oNDragListener.But ist did not work for me.

Comment: in that case, you have to change view.setscalex() in the onDragListner